# Flutter one time animation for each start of app(not first run)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to use some animations on my main screen but only when app start, because while using the app users have to navigate back to main screen oftenly and those animations makes loading time and became annoying to see again and again.. So, is there any way to make animatoins active only the first start(not first run) of app then make them inactive till restart the app?

Here is a simple code; not same but similar logic with the animations I've used, my code is too complex to copy-paste so I'm sending a sample code which I send to another question as answer;

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
 runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     title: 'Flutter Demo',
     theme: ThemeData(
       primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
     ),
     home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
   );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

 final String title;

 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: Center(
       child: ListView(
         children: [Container(
           color: Colors.blue,
           height: 1000,
           child: Column(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
             children: <Widget>[
               SlideFadeTransition(
                   delayStart: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                   offset: 2,
                   child: new Text('Test Text 1')),
               SlideFadeTransition(
                   delayStart: Duration(milliseconds: 1200),
                   offset: 4,
                   child: new Text('Test Text 2'))
             ],
           ),
         ),
           Container(
             color: Colors.red,
             height: 1000,
             child: Column(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
               children: <Widget>[
                 SlideFadeTransition(
                     delayStart: Duration(milliseconds: 1200),
                     offset: 2,
                     child: new Text('Test Text 1')),
                 SlideFadeTransition(
                     delayStart: Duration(milliseconds: 2400),
                     offset: 4,
                     child: new Text('Test Text 2'))
               ],
             ),
           ),
           Container(
             color: Colors.orange,
             height: 1000,
             child: Column(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
               children: <Widget>[
                 SlideFadeTransition(
                     delayStart: Duration(milliseconds: 1200),
                     offset: 2,
                     child: new Text('Test Text 1')),
                 SlideFadeTransition(
                     delayStart: Duration(milliseconds: 2400),
                     offset: 4,
                     child: new Text('Test Text 2'))
               ],
             ),
           ),
 ]
   )
   )
   );
 }
}


enum Direction { vertical, horizontal }

class SlideFadeTransition extends StatefulWidget {
 ///The child on which to apply the given [SlideFadeTransition]
 final Widget child;

 ///The offset by which to slide and [child] into view from [Direction].
 ///Defaults to 0.2
 final double offset;

 ///The curve used to animate the [child] into view.
 ///Defaults to [Curves.easeIn]
 final Curve curve;

 ///The direction from which to animate the [child] into view. [Direction.horizontal]
 ///will make the child slide on x-axis by [offset] and [Direction.vertical] on y-axis.
 ///Defaults to [Direction.vertical]
 final Direction direction;

 ///The delay with which to animate the [child]. Takes in a [Duration] and
 /// defaults to 0.0 seconds
 final Duration delayStart;

 ///The total duration in which the animation completes. Defaults to 800 milliseconds
 final Duration animationDuration;

 SlideFadeTransition({
   @required this.child,
   this.offset = 0.2,
   this.curve = Curves.easeIn,
   this.direction = Direction.vertical,
   this.delayStart = const Duration(seconds: 0),
   this.animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
 });
 @override
 _SlideFadeTransitionState createState() => _SlideFadeTransitionState();
}

class _SlideFadeTransitionState extends State<SlideFadeTransition>
   with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
 Animation<Offset> _animationSlide;

 AnimationController _animationController;

 Animation<double> _animationFade;

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   _animationController = AnimationController(
     vsync: this,
     duration: widget.animationDuration,
   );

   //configure the animation controller as per the direction
   if (widget.direction == Direction.vertical) {
     _animationSlide =
         Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0, widget.offset), end: Offset(0, 0))
             .animate(CurvedAnimation(
           curve: widget.curve,
           parent: _animationController,
         ));
   } else {
     _animationSlide =
         Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(widget.offset, 0), end: Offset(0, 0))
             .animate(CurvedAnimation(
           curve: widget.curve,
           parent: _animationController,
         ));
   }

   _animationFade =
       Tween<double>(begin: -1.0, end: 1.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
         curve: widget.curve,
         parent: _animationController,
       ));

   Timer(widget.delayStart, () {
     _animationController.forward();
   });
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return FadeTransition(
     opacity: _animationFade,
     child: SlideTransition(
       position: _animationSlide,
       child: widget.child,
     ),
   );}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You can define a `bool` `firstRun` = `true` 
Step 2: When Navigate to other page set `firstRun` to `false` 
Step 3: In `_SlideFadeTransitionState` 's `build` method check if not `firstRun` and return `widget.child` directly

```
return firstRun? FadeTransition(...widget.child) : widget.child
```

working demo

[image]

code snippet

```
bool firstRun = true;
...
RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Open route'),
        onPressed: () {
          firstRun = false;
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
          );
        },
      )
...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('first run ${firstRun}');
    return firstRun? FadeTransition(
      opacity: _animationFade,
      child: SlideTransition(
        position: _animationSlide,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    ) : widget.child;
  }
```

full code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

bool firstRun = true;

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: ListView(children: [
      Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        height: 1000,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SlideFadeTransition(
                delayStart: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                offset: 2,
                child: new Text('Test Text 1')),
            SlideFadeTransition(
                delayStart: Duration(milliseconds: 1200),
                offset: 4,
                child: new Text('Test Text 2'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 1000,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SlideFadeTransition(
                delayStart: Duration(milliseconds: 1200),
                offset: 2,
                child: new Text('Test Text 1')),
            SlideFadeTransition(
                delayStart: Duration(milliseconds: 2400),
                offset: 4,
                child: new Text('Test Text 2'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.orange,
        height: 1000,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SlideFadeTransition(
                delayStart: Duration(milliseconds: 1200),
                offset: 2,
                child: new Text('Test Text 1')),
            SlideFadeTransition(
                delayStart: Duration(milliseconds: 2400),
                offset: 4,
                child: new Text('Test Text 2'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Open route'),
        onPressed: () {
          firstRun = false;
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
          );
        },
      ),
    ])));
  }
}

enum Direction { vertical, horizontal }

class SlideFadeTransition extends StatefulWidget {
  ///The child on which to apply the given [SlideFadeTransition]
  final Widget child;

  ///The offset by which to slide and [child] into view from [Direction].
  ///Defaults to 0.2
  final double offset;

  ///The curve used to animate the [child] into view.
  ///Defaults to [Curves.easeIn]
  final Curve curve;

  ///The direction from which to animate the [child] into view. [Direction.horizontal]
  ///will make the child slide on x-axis by [offset] and [Direction.vertical] on y-axis.
  ///Defaults to [Direction.vertical]
  final Direction direction;

  ///The delay with which to animate the [child]. Takes in a [Duration] and
  /// defaults to 0.0 seconds
  final Duration delayStart;

  ///The total duration in which the animation completes. Defaults to 800 milliseconds
  final Duration animationDuration;

  SlideFadeTransition({
    @required this.child,
    this.offset = 0.2,
    this.curve = Curves.easeIn,
    this.direction = Direction.vertical,
    this.delayStart = const Duration(seconds: 0),
    this.animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
  });
  @override
  _SlideFadeTransitionState createState() => _SlideFadeTransitionState();
}

class _SlideFadeTransitionState extends State<SlideFadeTransition>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<Offset> _animationSlide;

  AnimationController _animationController;

  Animation<double> _animationFade;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: widget.animationDuration,
    );

    //configure the animation controller as per the direction
    if (widget.direction == Direction.vertical) {
      _animationSlide =
          Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0, widget.offset), end: Offset(0, 0))
              .animate(CurvedAnimation(
        curve: widget.curve,
        parent: _animationController,
      ));
    } else {
      _animationSlide =
          Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(widget.offset, 0), end: Offset(0, 0))
              .animate(CurvedAnimation(
        curve: widget.curve,
        parent: _animationController,
      ));
    }

    _animationFade =
        Tween<double>(begin: -1.0, end: 1.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      curve: widget.curve,
      parent: _animationController,
    ));

    Timer(widget.delayStart, () {
      _animationController.forward();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('first run ${firstRun}');
    return firstRun? FadeTransition(
      opacity: _animationFade,
      child: SlideTransition(
        position: _animationSlide,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    ) : widget.child;
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigate back to first route when tapped.
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I made some arrangements because I keep my animations settings in different dart file but  it works as I wanted, thanks a lot.